# Harry Potter fan fiction where Sirius Black rescues Harry as a child

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

This was a Harry Potter fan fiction in which Sirius rescues Harry when he is a kid, walks to his uncle's cabin, and uses a "cooking wand"?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This question really doesn't have very much detail.  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking story-id questions in case there are more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: @closevoters for the record, Googling [`harry potter fanfiction "cooking wand"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=harry+potter+fanfiction+%22cooking+wand%22) yields a grand total of 7 results. That doesn't seem too broad. But if you think it is, please provide a couple of examples of fanfictions having 1/ Sirius saving kid Harry and 2/ using a cooking wand

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like [The Promise](https://fanfiction.net/s/4674115/14/) by ZairaAlbereo. Here’s the part with the cooking wand:

> But Sirius knew immediately what it was, and had to stifle a laugh. It was a cooking wand! He had seen James mother using it often enough, but he'd never guessed his uncle would own such a thing. In his opinion, it had always been for old little ladies really. Or for squibs, as his mother would have scoffed, although that was rubbish, since you needed to be a wizard to use one as well. But his uncle had been a rather gruff old man, who was out in the woods most of the time hunting or fishing or what not. And he had a cooking wand. Sirius snorted.

Comment: Yesss, that´s the one, thank you